# Absolute positioning within a div and overflow

Tags: html, css

Let's assume that I have OuterDiv of unknown size and InnerDiv 10px x 10px within the OuterDiv. What I want to achieve is absolute positioning of InnerDiv within OuterDiv (the easy part), so that position (0,0) means top left corner of OuterDiv and (the hard part) position (-5, 0) means that only right half of InnerDiv is visible (the overflowed part is hidden). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `overflow: hidden` css attribute.
Is the following piece of code working for you?

```
<div id="outer" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

     <div id="inner" style="height: 10px; width: 10px; display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; left: -5px; background: #f00;">

     </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to apply `overflow: hidden` on the outer element and position the inner element with `left: -5px` like so:

```
#outer {
  height: 200px; /* Must give explicit height since contents are absolute */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#inner {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -5px;
}
```

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/1397390) of a working example.